# How frequently the Kaggle Stackoverflow BigQuery dataset is Updated?

Tags: google-bigquery, kaggle

I am looking for a dataset which has continuous updates of the stack overflow data. I was checking the [kaggle bigquery stack overflow dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/stackoverflow) and noticed that the dataset is being quarterly updated.

[image]

But, I can see from the [metadata](https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/stackoverflow/metadata) that the last updated was in March 2019.

[image]

Is there any source where I can get the continuous updates of stack overflow data or updates within a 1 month period?

Comment: There is no public issue tracker for the Public Dataset Program for now, however you can send an inquiry to **bq-public-data@google.com** as they are [maintaining the available public datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data#contact_us) including Stackoverflow dataset in BigQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the metadata says different, I found from the tables data that they are updating the dataset quarterly.

The most updated data can be found from in the [stack exchange data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).

[image]

[image]